# Descending order in List<Guid> is different then IQueryable OrderByDescending

Tags: sql-server, linq, sorting, guid

I am working on .NET CORE 2.0 application and part of that I am require sort GUID in descending order. I have list of GUID in List pass to another method where this collection is sorted in descending order but I have found result is different then use IQueryable Linq as `select(x=>x.id).OrderByDescending(x=>x)` also comparing with SQL Server, the second option seems correct.

I need List sort in descending order output as same result as IQueryable Linq as `select(x=>x.id).OrderByDescending(x=>x)`

```
 List<Guid> sortedList =  
       C95F4897-35D8-409D-BF0E-B0D6E1BCAC55
       D867FD57-F728-46E9-BFF0-F168BAC674C4
       F05BCAA7-600E-406F-B9F3-7CD839FFC98B
       383525C6-F158-431C-A6A5-B42FF3CBF5AE
```

I have also tried following code but not getting correct result

```
     var s1 = sortedList.OrderByDescending(i => i);

        sortedList.Sort();
        sortedList.Reverse();
```

### data without sort

[image]

### data IQueryable sort in LINQ (this is result I am after but from collection.sort

[image]

### data sort from collection

[image]

Comment: Can you illustrate with data how the order is different?

Comment: `List` is in memory operation when `IQueryable` is executing at the remote server. Could you please check what does the IQueryable query translates into Sql Server and also what is difference between the results, if it is consistent. Need more clarity in your question.

Comment: What is the data type of the column, is it string or `uniqueidentifier`?

Comment: I have added screen shots of results above in my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call .OrderByDescending on a list, you are calling [Enumerable.OrderByDescending](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx). Conversely, when you are calling .OrderByDescending on a linq query, you are calling [Queryable.OrderByDescending](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549264(v=vs.110).aspx).
The difference (the difference that matters here) is the enumerable method uses the default comparer (in this case of datatype `GUID`), while the queryable method is converted to a sql statement which is executed on the database, hence using the SQL comparer (of `uniqueidentifier`). The `GUID` comparer uses all 16 bytes equally, while in SQL the last 6 bytes are the most significant ([Source1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/comparing-guid-and-uniqueidentifier-values), [Source2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2006/11/06/how-are-guids-compared-in-sql-server-2005/)(old, but still valid)).

You say you desire the result of the queryable method, while using the enumerable method (in essence). You can achieve this by using the `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlGuid` datatype instead of `system.Guid`. You can simply cast your Guid's to SqlGuid's. Alternatively, and probably a much cleaner solution, you can create your own [comparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx) using `SqlGuid.CompareTo` method, and use that in the order by: `OrderByDescending(x => x, new MyComparer())` .